# Does a MacBook run differently if the HD is seen as a external drive by the OS?

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, performance

I had to reinstall a new internal HD and now my computer works but the HD is seen as an external drive. Does this matter? Will performance, any apps or my VM be affected by this?

Comment: This question, as written, makes no sense.  Are you saying that you *replaced* an internal MacBook HDD with another, but it is now seeing it as an *external drive*?  If this is the case, can you post a screenshot that depicts your problem?  As for performance Apple (or any computer for the matter) doesn't care if it's internal or external, what will affect performance is the actual performance of the connection

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying. How could this connection vary? Isn't there only one way to connect an internal HD? I don't know because a repair shop did the work.

Comment: USB 3.0 is 5Gb/s  SATA III is 6Gb/s;  that's how the connections vary.  OS X is not going to slow anything down because it thinks it's external; that not how this works.

Comment: Buts it's not an USB. It should be a SATA but is perceived as a USB?

Comment: No.  You are confusing connection type with device location.  According to your description, it's perceived as ***external***.  USB has nothing to do whether the device is internal or external.  Example:  your touchpad is off the USB bus and it's an "internal device."  Look in your System Profiler and see if your drive show up as USB.

Comment: @Alla why have you mentioned USB?

Comment: @Mark - USB is most easily perceived as external....no other reason than that.

Comment: What exactly says it is an external drive - we need screenshots of actual error messages

Comment: Please give me until later this afternoon to provide screenshots (6hrs or so)